# TypeError: MLPClassifier() got an unexpected keyword argument 'algorithm'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have just installed scikit-learn v0.18 dev package.

when I call the following on iPython;

```
>>> from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
>>> clf = MLPClassifier(algorithm='l-bfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)
```

there is no error. But when I write a python script file and run the code on it, I get the following error:

```
clf = MLPClassifier(algorithm='l-bfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1, warm_start=True)
TypeError: MLPClassifier() got an unexpected keyword argument 'algorithm'
```

I don't know where is the problem. How can I fix this bug?

Comment: The calls are slightly different (plus `warm_start=True` in the second call) but I think you're likely using different Python interpreters (with different `sklearn` versions) in IPython and when running the script. Check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're gonna want to change the `algorithm` param to `solver`. See the [documentation for that estimator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) and the [repo for dev](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L682).

Comment: This answer fixes the reported issue. I ran into yet another issue, 'l-bfgs' should be 'lbfgs'.

Comment: Thaks @auro . You saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

clf = MLPClassifier(solver='l-bfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1, warm_start=True)
```

Just replace `algorithm` by `solver`

But when you fit data in one line:

```
X,y = make_moons(n_samples=100, noise=0.25, random_state=3)
X_trian, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, stratify=y, random_state=42)
mlpc = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

replace `l-bfgs` by `lbfgs`